# Convert http and http://www to https and https://www

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I’ve changed my base url in config file to https://mywebsite

However, if I enter www.mywebsite it does not change to https nor does it change if I enter https://www.mywebsite

We do not want this to affect associated APIs and images. Is this possible?

We just want to secure the url for our different social media avenues.

Our website is created using codeigniter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add these lines in htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myhost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php(/[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ myhost.com/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks - it caused the app associated with the website not to work.  Received this error message: JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format.

Comment: Anyone able to assist?